# Android DialogFragment margin on dim

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

Is it possible to not have a part of the screen dimmed when a DialogFragment shows? There are a few Views at the top of the screen that I want to remain at full brightness when DialogFragment shows up. Everything else should remain dimmed. I was hoping for something like a dim marginTop.

Comment: You want to disable dim?

Comment: @azizbekian No. Just have part of the screen not dimmed.